# How to remove class on link click using pure js?

Tags: javascript

How to remove the 'open' class when clicking on

```
<a class="menu-link"></a>
```

[image]

```
// this is how I add the class on button click
document.getElementById('navigation-toggle').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.toggle('open');
}
// and i'm trying to remove it on click on the link
document.querySelector('.menu-link').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.remove('open');
}
```

Comment: `event.target.classList.remove("open")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple links so you have to add event listener to all of them

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link').forEach(link => link.onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.remove('open');
})
```

I would also consider using `addEventListener`. And you can read about event delegation.